# Angular 2 http ajax calls generating multiple sessions on PHP

Tags: php, angular2-http

When I hit a GET route from the browser it produces a stable and reusable PHP session, but when I hit the same GET route via http through an Angular 2 Service it produces a different session on each hit.  Is it possible I am doing something wrong or is everyone else just using JWT for authentication?

Service looks like.

```
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getUserRole(email, jwt){
    let coded = btoa(jwt);
    let cEmail = btoa(email)
    let profile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/'+profile.clientID+'/user/'+coded+'/'+cEmail)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }

}
```

I am using the Slim PHP framework on the back end.

Comment: That is not really a JWT in there, you are just imagining things.  :-)

Comment: What is it the JWT?

Comment: Java Web Token, is what many people use for authentication.  I am calling one of my variables jwt.